# Unable to delete file via jquery to MVC action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am invoking a action method via jquery and trying to delete a file. But nothing happens. The file still exist.

**Following is jquery Code**

```
$("#pictureRemove").click(function (e) {
            $("#pictureImage").html("<img src='../../Content/Images/noDefaultImage_100.gif'/>");
            $(this).hide();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("Remove", "Category")',
                data: { fileName: $('#pictureTitle').attr('src') },
                dataType: 'json'
                    // User your JSON response.
            });
        });
```

**Following is the action method code**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Remove(string fileName)
    {
        string completFileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/" + fileName);
        System.IO.File.Delete(completFileName);
        return Json(true);
    }
```

Comment: the file still remains on the server? if ajax is doing fine its not the case of jquery ... see the firebug console to confirm if the ajax was successful

Comment: are you getting an exception??

Comment: I have no idea....Never worked with jquery so bit short on the knowledge and tracing the error. BTW, Everything goes smooth. No warning, errors etc. But still the file remains in tact.

Comment: is the completeFileName pointing to the right file??

Comment: I don't know how to be sure as to whether the method is getting hit or not. Does the code seem right ? Actually i borrowed it from here and there and fixed it.

Comment: ya the completeFileName must be correct because the fileName i am passing is correct and then just adding the Server.MapPath. I don't think it should be something related with that

Comment: Extremely sorry guys .... i mistaken pictureImage for a img element whereas its a span element. So, i needed to use `$('#pictureTitle').text()` .... Haven't felt this stupid for long time. I coded pictureImage a minute ago and forgot that it was a span.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On this line:

```
data: { fileName: $('#pictureTitle').attr('src') }
```

you seem to be passing the fileName parameter to the controller action from the src parameter of some image. So I suppose that you have some image like this:

```
<img id="pictureTitle" src="/Content/images/foo.jpg" />
```

so you are passing `/Content/images/foo.jpg` so in your controller action you are trying to delete `Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images//Content/images/foo.jpg")` which is translated to `c:\wwwroot\Content\Images\Content\images\foo.jpg` which is unlikely to exist and an exception is thrown.

Simply put a breakpoint in your controller action and inspect the different parameters.

This being said exposing a controller action that takes a filename and deletes the file on the server is a huge security hole in your application.

Comment: f**** hell....I was being as stupid as one can imagine. Actually pictureTile is a span which holds just the filename. So i needed to use `$('#pictureTitle').text()` .... Extremely sorry for this silly mistake and stupidity. Thanks Darin for putting this up and getting my head straight

Comment: My controller uses Authorize attribute for admins. Still security can be a factor ??

Comment: Yes, because the file path is being injected to your delete code without validation. A malicious attacker could craft a HTTP request that sends "../../../Domain.dll".

Comment: You're also writing business logic into your controller which should only be concerned with display information, the delete should be controlled by a service that your controller calls. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay, yes, still a security thread especially if you don't trust your users. If anyone can sign to your site that would mean that anyone can delete files just by setting this parameter to whatever he wants.

Comment: thanks StuperUser and Darin....I will look into this matter and see how can i application more secure against such attacks....